# No runnable method junit/java

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to run a test to compare if the user input has the same amount of words as the specified expected length (4).

I right-click the source file in NetBeans and select "Test file", but for some reason, I keep getting the error: "No runnable method" when there clearly is one? Can someone explain to me what is going on?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class UserMainTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testMain() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = "";
        line = input.nextLine();
        String arr [] = line.split(" ");
        int expected = 4;
        int actual = arr.length;
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you attempting to run this code?

Comment: @khelwood Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question. I'm running it by right-clicking the java file and clicking "Test file"

Comment: @user16320675 I'm using netbeans. I'm right-clicking both the original java file and the test file (on the left under projects) in an attempt to run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you change your code a bit and change it, you can do it like this

```
    @DisplayName("testMain")
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"1 2 3 4"})
    public void testMain(String line){

        String arr[]=line.split(" ");
        int expected=4;
        int actual=arr.length;

        assertThat(expected).isEqualTo(actual);
    }
```

2. If you are using junit4 you may get an error
   if you use junit5 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.

```
JUnit 4 org.junit.Test 

Junit 5 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! It doesn't seem to be working, but I'm starting to think it might be a problem with my IDE rather than your code :/

Comment: Oh my god the edit worked thank you so much!! I spent all night trying to figure this out but I can finally sleep now